# Software to find and delete duplicate files in Windows 8

Tags: windows, file-management

Recently I copied a lot of photos and videos in my system. Now there is 2 or more than 2 copies of each in my system. I want to delete the copies. I don't have much time to look it by myself. Is there a software that searches for duplicate files in my PC and deletes it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 suggestions, both of which run on 32bit/64bit Windows 8:

[Funduc Duplicate File Finder](http://www.funduc.com/dupfiles.htm) (Shareware)

This finds and displays duplicate files using a graphical UI, and allows you to select and delete duplicates fairly easily.

[Swiss File Knife](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/) (Freeware)

This is a command line-based utility (only 1 .exe file, no installation) that does *many* things.  It includes a command for finding duplicate files - type "sfk dupfind" on the command line to see the help.   You would probably also need to use the chaining support with the delete command to do the deletion - type "sfk delete" and "sfk help chain" to see the help for these.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! I'd normally say this is  that this post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer however given the question I suppose it is minimal but okay. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer - like do mention what OS(es) they support specifically do both of those work with Windows 8?